# glyphicon is not working

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

my glyphicons are not working in my "dropdown" class. but it works in my "dropdown-menu" class. my first  tag, the text is loaded through database, but the glyphicon is not showing up. what can I do?

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class="dropdown">         
      <a id ="lblnames" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" runat="server" style="color:white; cursor:pointer"># <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>

     <ul class ="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="Account/Manage.aspx" style="font-family:Calibri">Manage Account <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog pull-right"></span></a></li>

     <li><a id="endsession1" href="Account/forLogOut.aspx" style="font-family:Calibri">Log Out <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out pull-right"></span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it seems fine. The problem is that you have set the color to white in your inline CSS here:

```
<a id ="lblnames" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" runat="server" style="color:white; cursor:pointer"># <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
```

I changed the color to something else and it worked fine. :)